# How do you use unlocked items?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I just started playing Bad Company 2 this weekend, and I earned the motion sensor for the recon class. I can't figure out for the life of me how to use it or equip it? Is there some control on pc to use these unlocked items?

Answer (score 4):

As the others have explained, most unlocked items/weapons have to be chosen at the loadout screen.

However the motion sensor will **always** be equipped once you've unlocked them (and respawned once). You can switch to them with the mousewheel or by pressing `4`.

Comment: There's at least 1 item for each class that will automatically equip. Assault-ammo hub, Medic-Medic hub and defib, Engineer-Repair tool and as said above motion mines for Snipers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pick equipment at the class-select screen when you're waiting to spawn, there *might* be an arrow next to the class name you have to click for the weapon list to expand.

Answer (score 0):

Once you unlock items or weapons, you have to wait till respawn to change your loadout. Just highlight the class you want and a menu will pop out (you may need to move the mouse or joystick, I can't recall exactly) and you can pick from the unlocked stuff.